# Flask: Site reload prior check with database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I try to build a flask site with a very simple dictionary. A user can save words which are stored in a simple sqlite database. All that works fine, but if I try to implement a simple test on the vocabulary I can´t get consistent data from the database. The site is called, and after validate_on_submit it is relaoded so my choice from the database is a new one. Sorry for the bad description, may be it is gettinger clearer if I show you the code. I followed the CoreySchaefer Tutorials and the structur, so

```
# forms.py
# ...

class VocTestForm(FlaskForm):
    german = StringField('Deutsch', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Check')


# models.py 
# ...  
  
class Dictionary(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    engl = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    german = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.engl} {self.german}"


# voc_test.html

{% extends "base_layout.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf%}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{check_word.engl}}</h1>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
{% endblock %}


# routes.py
# ...

@app.route('/voc_test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voc_test():
    form = VocTestForm()
    content = Dictionary.query.all()
    check_word = random.choice(content)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if str(form.german.data) == str(check_word.german):
            flash(f'Correct', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('voc_test'))
        else:
            flash(f'wrong', 'danger')
            form.german = " "
    return render_template('voc_test.html', form=form, check_word=check_word
```

The last function is not working. If I compare the String from the form with the String from the database the random.choice has already chosen a new word. How can I prevent this?
Thanks for the help

Steffen

Answer (score 0):

If I've read what you're trying to do right, you could use the random library to generate a number. Then pull the item at that index from the dictionary.

Comment: Okay, I guess my question is quite confusing. My Problem is: the function voc_test() is called, chooses a word and diplays that word. When a user then "validate_on_submit" the function is called again and then there is again a random_word chosen which is most probably another word than before. Eventually the if statemant evaluates wrong, even if the user writes the correct word (the correct word from the first call). So to break it down: validate_on_submit() reloads the function and that changes the selection of the word